# how to read protect some of the files

Tags: authentication, permissions, flask

I am sure this question should be asked before but I have no idea what to search to get to the solution! Here it goes: lets say I have two folders on a server `secure` and `unsecure`; the files in the `unsecure` folder should be accessible for everybody while the files in the `secure` folder should be only accessible by a group of users. I want both the files to have a url similar to `www.example.com/secure/file_s` and `www.example.com/unsecure/file_us`. But if you are not logged in, and tried to access the `file_s`, it should ask you to login first. I am using flask for the server side. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are you using for authentication?

Comment: I add the user in the session upon loging in and check the g.user later to authenticate. similar to what is described here: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins
Please let me know if this does not address your question

Answer (score 0):

Using the [post you mentioned](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins), access to a view can be restricted to logged in users using Flask-Login's `login_required` decorator.

```
from flask.ext.login import login_required

@app.route('/secure/<filename>')
@login_required
def secure_file(filename):
    pass


@app.route('/unsecure/<filename>')
def unsecure_file(filename):
    pass
```